# Missing significant number of transactions when using measurement protocol and non-interactive

Tags: google-analytics, transactions, e-commerce, google-analytics-api, measurement-protocol

Using google analytics and it's measurement protocol, I am trying to track eCommerce transactions based on my customers (who aren't end-consumers meaning not sparse unique userid's, locations, etc...) which have a semantic idea of a "sale" with revenue.

The problem is that not all of my logged requests to the ga mp API are resulting in "rows" of transactions when looking at conversions->ecommerce->transactions.   And additionally, the revenue reported is respectively missing too.   An example of the discrepancy is listing all my non-zero transaction revenue API calls, I should see 321 transactions in the analytics dashboard.  However, I see only 106... 30%!!!   This is about the same every day even tweaking some attributes which I would think would force uniqueness of a session or transaction.

A semantic difference is that a unique consumer (cid or uid) can send a "t=transaction" with a unique "ti" (transaction id) which overlap and are not serial.   I say this to suggest that *maybe* there is some session related deduplication happening even though my "ti" attribute is definitely unique across my notion of a "transaction".  In other words, a particular cid/uid maybe have many different ti's in the same minute.

I have no google analytics javascript or client-side components in use and are simply not applicable to how I need to use google analytics which takes me to using the measurement protocol.

Using the hit-builder, /debug/collect, and logging of any http non-200 responses, I see absolutely no indication that *all* of my "t=transaction" messages would not be received and processed.   Some of the typical debugging points I think are eliminated with this list of what I have tried

- sent message via /collect
- sent multiple message via /batch (t=transaction and t=item)
- sent my UUID of my consumer as cid=, uid= and both
- tried with and without "sc=start" to ensure there was no session deduplication of a transaction
- tried with and without ua (user-agent) and uip (ip override) since it's server side but hits from consumers do come from different originations sometimes
- took into consideration my timezone (UTC-8) and how my server logs these requests (UTC)
- waited 24 to 48 hours to ensure data
- ecommerce is turned on for my view
- amount of calls to measurement protocol are < 10000 per day so I don't think I am hitting any limits

I have t=event messages too although I am taking a step back from using them for now until I can see that data is represented at least to 90%+.

Here is an example t=transaction call.

```
curl \
  --verbose \
  --request POST \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data 'ta=customer1&t=transaction&sc=start&v=1&cid=4b014cff-ccce-44c2-bfb8-e0f05fc7827c&tr=0.0&uid=4b014cff-ccce-44c2-bfb8-e0f05fc7827c&tid=UA-xxxxxxxxx-1&ti=5ef618370b01009807f780c5' \
  'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done a very good job debugging so unfortunately there isn't much left to do, **a few things left to check**:

- **View bot/spider filter**: disable this option to be on the safe sife

[image]

- **[500 hits / session](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/limits-quotas#universal_properties)**: if you're sending lots of hits for the same `cid/uid` within `30 minutes` (whatever your [session-timeout](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795871?hl=en) is), then these would be recorded as per of the same session and thus you could reach quota limit.
- **[10M hits / property / month](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/limits-quotas#non-premium)**: you didn't mention overall properly volume so I'm mentioning this in case
- **[Paylod limit of 1KB = 8192 bytes](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference#using-post)**: I've seen people running into that issue when tracking transactions with a crazy amount of products attached to it
- **Other view filters**: same thing, you didn't mention so I'm mentioning just in case

---

**Further debugging could include**:

- **Using events instead of transactions:** the problem with transactions is that they're a black box, if they don't show up you don't have any debug. I personally always track my transactions via events and I set a copy of the Ecommerce payload as event label (`JSON` string) for debugging, so if the event is present I know it's not a data ingestion issue but most likely my ecommerce payload which is malformed (and I have the event label to debug it), and if the event is missing then it's a data ingestion problem. **See below example, replace `UA-XXXXXXX-1` with your own**:

```
v=1&t=event&tid=UA-XXXXXXX-1&cid=1373730658.1593409595&ec=Ecommerce&ea=Purchase&ti=T12345&ta=Online%20Store&tr=15.25&tt=0.00&ts=0.00&tcc=SUMMER_SALE&pa=purchase&pr1nm=Triblend%20Android%20T-Shirt&pr1id=12345&pr1pr=15.25&pr1br=Google&pr1ca=Apparel&pr1va=Gray&pr1qt=1&pr1cc=&el=%7B%22purchase%22%3A%7B%22actionField%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22T12345%22%2C%22affiliation%22%3A%22Online%20Store%22%2C%22revenue%22%3A%2215.25%22%2C%22tax%22%3A%220.00%22%2C%22shipping%22%3A%220.00%22%2C%22coupon%22%3A%22SUMMER_SALE%22%7D%2C%22products%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22Triblend%20Android%20T-Shirt%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2212345%22%2C%22price%22%3A%2215.25%22%2C%22brand%22%3A%22Google%22%2C%22category%22%3A%22Apparel%22%2C%22variant%22%3A%22Gray%22%2C%22quantity%22%3A1%2C%22coupon%22%3A%22%22%7D%5D%7D%7D
```

- **Using a data collection platform like [Segment](https://segment.com/docs/connections/spec/ecommerce/v2/)**: which will give you an extra level of debugging via their debugger (although their payload syntax is != than GA so that introduces another level of complexity, it does help me from time to time to spot issues with the underlying data though as I'm familiar with its syntax).

Comment: It appears that the bot/spider filter was the culprit.   Thanks for the additional insight; it certainly helped me out.   Still a bit mysterious unfortunately.